# Windows Service - .NET Core - not showing designer page

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm using Windows Forms in .NET Core 6 and I tried to create a Windows service as well. When I created it, I saw that the designer page of Windows service loads more time and I'm not able to add the installer to the service. What should be done to add the installer?

This is a screenshot for illustration:

https://prnt.sc/ZuBKUUSBXk3N

Video link: https://ttprivatenew.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/anilkumar-aitechindia/attachments/22458726/TinyTake27-11-2023-07-05-05.mp4

Note: should use only .NET Core. In "legacy" .NET framework, I'm able to do it.

Comment: Check out our latest Preview of the WinForms Designer, just be sure to turn it on in tools->options->Preview Features->Use the Preview Windows Forms Designer for .NET Core apps or may be provided solution in link will work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70214006/visual-studio-2022-winforms-designer-hang-on-loading-designer

Comment: @Vishvadeepsingh,

I tried with the above link and it didn't work out for me. Please check the video link below.

Link: https://ttprivatenew.s3.amazonaws.com/pulse/anilkumar-aitechindia/attachments/22458726/TinyTake27-11-2023-07-05-05.mp4

Comment: are you getting any assembly error?

Comment: No, It's loading infinitely. In the video, I have shown it in the last. It does not come to an end.

Comment: please select desktop instead of console application

Comment: Yes, tried with that method as well. Please check the image below.

Image: https://prnt.sc/F24nHXb0DvXt

Comment: create new changing it from properties will not work

Comment: Can you please list out the steps? @Vishvadeepsingh

Comment: check this link for detail of the steps:
https://c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-window-service-in-net-core/

Comment: I need to have the windows as like dot net framework windows service. By this way, I can have installer.

Image: https://prnt.sc/rLG6MLW_A5KB

Comment: Thanks for the help by providing the link @Vishvadeepsingh. But, this is a manual creation of the windows service which does not have installer as like the normal dot net framework windows service. When I add MSI setup build, the windows service installer helps me in installing and starting the services and stop the service when the application is uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

`Windows Services` created manually in VS2022 are based on the `.Net Framework` by default, which is why we can't open this designer page.

If you create a Windows Service based on the `.NET Framework`, you won't have any problems.

If you want to create a Windows Service based on `.NET Core`, you can refer to the steps below, which are also very simple and convenient.

#### Steps

[1. Create a Worker Service app from the .NET Core template.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

*Here is my test result:* [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77444953/7687666)

[2. Create a Windows Service installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service-with-installer?tabs=ext)